# change background image of a div when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, css, liferay

I hide the default checkbox and use a div with custom checkbox image instead:

```
<aui:form>
<c:if
    test="<%=company.isAutoLogin() && !PropsValues.SESSION_DISABLED%>">
    <div class="rememberImage ftr" id="rememberImg">
        <aui:input checked="<%=rememberMe%>" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe"
                            type="checkbox" cssClass="remember"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
</form>

//omiited

<aui:script use="aui-base">     
        function changeBG() {
            if (this.checked) {
                document.getElementById('rememberImg').style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/chk_none.png)';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('rememberImg').style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/chk_check.png)';
            }       
        }

        document.getElementById('_58_rememberMe').addEventListener('change', changeBG);


        var password = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />password');

        if (password) {
            password.on(
                'keypress',
                function(event) {
                    Liferay.Util.showCapsLock(event, '<portlet:namespace />passwordCapsLockSpan');
                }
            );
        }
    </aui:script>
```

This does not work at all. Any suggestions?? Much appreciated!

UPDATE: add more lines of code that I think maybe have problems

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: What does it do or not do? Is there any console output? Where is the JavaScript being called from, there doesn't seem to be any reference to it in the HTML you provided.

Comment: You should add onchange event listener, so your conditional statement not gonna be static and related to user activity

Comment: I would provide you a full answer, but I'm online from mobile :)

Comment: @blm I put the function in the AUI ready state so when the html is loaded, the function will run

Comment: @markoffden I'm wondering about that too, add some events, working on it

Comment: What about the image path? I don't think that it is a good idea to use a relative URL here - as that will be relative to the page (which may have different URLs depending on the host and friendly URL settings). Did you test it with a different style setting like `backgroundColor`?

Comment: I did, the image url is not the problem. If I do this: `if(document.getElementById('_58_rememberMe').value) { //change the background }` it works but when I click the background does not change, I guess I have to add the event to the checkbox. I'm stucked now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw a proper answer already above, but to avoid intruding HTML tags with JS listeners, what considered as not the best practice, I will offer you this solution...

```
function changeBG() {
    if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById('myElement').style.backgroundImage = 'url(.....)';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myElement').style.backgroundImage = 'url(.....)';
    }       
}

document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('change', changeBG);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: Add an onclick attribute to the checkbox that triggers a toggle function. As I cant test it with your code (missing the rest) I can only provide you an enxample where the body background gets changed

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" onclick="toggle();"> Click me

<script>

    function toggle() {

        if( document.getElementById("check").checked ) {
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It works for me, so you probably have another mistake in your code. Can u provide the whole code or look for possible js error in the console?

Comment: Whole jsp file is quite long and confused, I add some more, could you have a look

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
    margin: 20px 0;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none
}
input[type=checkbox]+label {
    background: url(http://s17.postimg.org/phsoii5vf/check.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    height: 18px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
    background: url(http://s2.postimg.org/zbjg138np/check_tick.jpg) no-repeat;    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1">
    <label for="chk1">Custom Checkbox1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2">
    <label for="chk2">Custom Checkbox2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3">
    <label for="chk3">Custom Checkbox3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk4">
    <label for="chk4">Custom Checkbox4</label>
</div>
```

not required javascript.you can do it from css.

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
<label for="chk">Custom Checkbox1</label>
</div>

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none
}
input[type=checkbox]+label {
    background: url(../images/check.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    height: 18px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
    background: url(../images/check_tick.png) no-repeat;    
}
```

Comment: the beckground is from another div, not the background of the input and the label

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
document.getElementById('rememberImage').style.background = 'url(../img/chk_check.png)';
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this line though, I had tried your suggestions but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SetBackground(elm){
  if($(elm).is(":checked"))
    {
  $("#rememberImage").css({"background-color":"gray"});
      }
  else
    {
    $("#rememberImage").css({"background-color":"white"});
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="rememberImage ftr" id="rememberImage">              
    <input checked="<%=rememberMe%>" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" onchange="SetBackground(this)"/>                        
</div>
```

I don't know how your custom checkbox works but, you can add onchange event and check if checkbox is checked then change the background of div.

Best regards

Comment: Unless already using it, using jQuery for this simple task is overkill, and better than hardcoding style information would be to move it to the page's css and use classes.